# How to inject data class in android with dagger where data class parameter have no default value?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

My data class like:

```
    data class Animal(var id:Int = 2)  {
    }
```

My Provides method in  module class like:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provide(): Animal {
        return Animal()
    }
```

I want to avoid default value in data class parameter.

Comment: Are you also want to avoid passing parameter from provider method?

Comment: yes bro. I want to avoid both.

Comment: @MushfiqueMonim You can make it optional by adding '?'.

Comment: Just as advice, don't mix properties with dependencies, you should probably construct your data class by hand with the primitives. Dagger `@Provides` are used mostly for classes that you can't annotate with `@Inject`.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the fields nullable and assign them as null.

Class:

```
data class Animal @Inject constructor(
    var id: Int? = null
) { }
```

Module:

```
@Provides
fun providesAnima(): Animal = Animal()
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid default value in parameter of data class you have to make it optional. In kotlin to make optional you have to use ? with the parameter.

```
data class Animal(var id:Int?=null)  {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as per **documentation** while using  data class primary constructor, it's must to pass at-least one parameter.
remove data from class, after removing data there is no need to pass at-least single parameter to Constructor  . hope this may helps you.

```
    class Animal()  {
           var id:Int = 2
    } 


@Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provide(): Animal {
        return Animal()
    }
```

Comment: Bro I want to inject data class

Comment: @MushfiqueMonim for data class its must to pass at-least single value  use simple class instead of data class.it will work